# Is it possible to change navigation bar color when I press a uibutton?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm wondering if its possible to change the color of Ui Navigation Bar color in Swift 2? Imagine whatsapp white color is changable to any color as the user press a button in settings for example. I have Googled for this online  but didn't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your buttons action just add

```
// UINavigationItem buttons
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor() 
// NavigationBar color
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UINavigationBar's property `barTintColor`.

Documentation: [UINavigationBar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/barTintColor)